# python 3.5.2 Dropbox module 'dropbox' has no attribute 'Dropbox'

Tags: python, api, dropbox, python-3.5, dbx

Hi I am kind of new to coding, I would like to make a small program that will upload my file to dropbox. I use python 3.5.2 and pycharm.
I followed the tutorial online.
1. pip install dropbox
2. copy and paste the link
3. execute
4. I got the following error

```
AttributeError: module 'dropbox' has no attribute 'Dropbox'
```

Any one know what to do in this situation? I been googling for a while, but couldn't come up with answers. Most I saw is the code for api V1

Following is my code

```
import dropbox 
dbx = dropbox.Dropbox('mytoken') 
dbx.users_get_current_account()
```

Tutorial I followed https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/python#tutorial

Comment: Did you save the script you're writing as `dropbox.py`? If so, use a different name.

Comment: And if that's not it, check what version of the `dropbox` library you have installed. The latest is 7.1.1.